# How do I query a GraphQl endpoint from node js without clunky string manipulation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I've searched around for ways to query a graphQl endpoint, but so far they've all had a pretty similar and clunky solution as I have: string building.  Here's a few links:

1. [querying graphql with node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811116/querying-graphql-with-node)
2. https://blog.apollographql.com/4-simple-ways-to-call-a-graphql-api-a6807bcdb355
3. https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-request

Ultimately, the code I'm running right now (and do not truly like) is:

```js
// replace anything that looks like this => %someVar
// with the value at vars[someVar]
function injectVars(query, vars) {
  return query.replace(/%([\d\w]+)/g, (_, varName) => {
    if (!vars.hasOwnProperty(varName)) {
      throw new Error(`Undefined variable: ${varName}`);
    }
    return vars[varName];
  });
}

// a query with the injection point "%userId"
const userQuery = `query getUser{
  user(
    id: "%userId"
  ) {
    id
    name
  }
}`;

// successful injection
const query = injectVars(userQuery, {
  userId: "some-id-123"
});
console.log(query);

// failed usage
const willFail = injectVars(userQuery, {
  nonVar: "missingUserId"
});
```

Problems I have with the code above:

1. Appears to be open to injection attacks
2. Not great type checking
3. Kind of a hassle with ENUMS, or type conversion (ie, take a date and make it string)
4. Not very extensible.  Would have to copy paste the same stuff a lot  for different iterations.
5. I'm new to this, and inherently don't trust my solutions yet.

**Anyways, how do I query a GraphQl endpoint from node js without clunky string manipulation?** Are there any tools/suggestions which would make this interaction more object oriented?

Answer (score 3):

Use [variables](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Language.Variables) as shown in the [official tutorial](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/passing-arguments).

> A GraphQL query can be parameterized with variables, maximizing query reuse, and avoiding costly string building in clients at runtime... Variables must be defined at the top of an operation and are in scope throughout the execution of that operation.

An example:

```
const query = `query getUser($id: ID!) {
  user(
    id: $id
  ) {
    id
    name
  }
}`
const variables = {
  id: 'someId'
}
fetch('/graphql', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query,
    variables,
  })
})
```

The JSON values you provide are parsed into the types you specify in your document (in the above example, an `ID` scalar). The variables will be validated by the GraphQL service so you could also skip checking if they are defined or the correct type. String values will be parsed into the appropriate enum value as long as the variable is declared as an enum type. IDs can be either Intergers or Strings. Input object types will be parsed and handled appropriately as well.

Comment: I do see how this helps with 1. safety and 3. enums, but it's still missing  2. The type checking is runtime (subpar) and 4. this looks like it would get really, really tiring for a function with 5 variables or more.

Comment: The only way to get better type checking without writing the validation logic yourself would be to use typescript. There's [tools](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling) for generating types from a schema and queries. That would give you compile-time type checking. So your options are: write the validation logic yourself, let the service handle it for you or switch to TS.

Comment: With regards to it being really "tiring" to write out multiple variable definitions, see [this recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57609307/6024220).

Comment: The only other solution that comes to mind is some kind of [query builder](https://github.com/atulmy/gql-query-builder) but variables are the standard, recommended way of handling dynamic inputs in GraphQL.